# how to yank from vim to system clipboard?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I'm using the latest version of vim 8.2.148 on the latest version of arch linux 5.5.6-arch1-1 with the latest version of Openbox window manager version 3.6.1.

I have written a document in vim and need to yank parts of it and paste them into a web form.

Is there a command in vim to yank to the system wide / openbox clipboard so that I can paste into the chromium web form?

Yank seems to work inside vim only.

Comment: Welcome to Vi/Vim SE. I'm sure I've seen answers here before that cover this. Did you try the Search box up top? If you found some but they were missing some critical detail please note that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First get into an appropriate visual mode. `v` selects the standard visual mode, `SHIFT-v` selects visual-line mode, and `CTRL-v` selects visual block mode. Next, select the text that you want to select. Finally, `"+y`.

- `"` means register.
- `+` specifies the system clipboard register.
- `y` is yank.

So `"+y` yanks into the system clipboard register.

more info on registers:

- `:help reg` inside vim
- Tutorial on vim registers: https://www.brianstorti.com/vim-registers/

Comment: I has to install neovim to get this to work. My native vim install did not support copy to system wide clipboard.

Comment: You might want to check your vimrc and plugins on your native vim install. Some sort of misconfiguration could be interfering. It should work out of the box. However, nvim is better anyway.

Comment: tried this on a fresh install of Linux Mint 20.1 and doesn't work. No custom .vimrc. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: vim-gtk package on ubuntu contains the +clipboard fyi

Comment: @Goblinhack I saw that + was not in the registers when using `:reg` and installing that thing solved it

Comment: This is an idiosyncracy that comes from using binary packages. If you want different options (like X11 and clipboard support) you have to install a different package. Ubuntu may have to support a non-X11 version of VIM so that some installation cd or rescue cd can work without xorg. You might consider investigating a source based package manager like Gentoo where you can control USE flags for packages. Opaque binary package management is inflexible and brittle and doesn't provide the best linux experience IMHO.

Comment: A tip: the "+ register will only work if vim is compiled with `clipboard` or `xterm_clipboard` This can be double checked with `vim --version|grep clipboard`  if the result is `-clipboard`  then it will not work if it' s `+clipboard` then the register will work. Usually `vimx` and neovim has this support enable